# How to make QCombobox expandable for hierarchical items?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qcombobox

i have a some dictionary variables such as :

```
{"Courses" : ["Math" , "Science" , "English"]} , 
{"Cars" : ["Ford" , "BMW" , "Mercedes"]} , etc.
```

i want to select values from qcombobox but  firstly, i need to keep the cursor at keys from qcombobox then select the value from the highlighted key.

```
Courses
Cars-->Ford
    -->BMW
    -->Mercedes
```

How can i do something like that? 
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `QPushButton` with a `QMenu` as I show below:

**PyQt4:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

data =[{
        "Courses": ["Math", "Science", "English"]
    },
    {
        "Cars": ["Ford", "BMW", "Mercedes"]
    }
]

class ComboBoxExpandable(QtGui.QPushButton):
    currentTextChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    pathChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def setData(self, value):
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        self.setMenu(menu)
        self.append_element(value, menu)
        menu.triggered.connect(self.on_triggered)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QAction)
    def on_triggered(self, action):
        self.setText(action.text())
        path = [action.text()] 
        w = action.parentWidget()
        while w.parentWidget() and isinstance(w.parentWidget(), QtGui.QMenu):
            path.insert(0, w.title())
            w = w.parentWidget()
        self.pathChanged.emit(path)
        self.currentTextChanged.emit(self.text())

    @staticmethod
    def append_element(value, menu):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for e in value:
                ComboBoxExpandable.append_element(e, menu)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            for k, v in value.items():
                ComboBoxExpandable.append_element(v, menu.addMenu(k))
        else:
            menu.addAction(value)


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        combo = ComboBoxExpandable()
        combo.setData(data)

        result_label = QtGui.QLabel()

        combo.currentTextChanged.connect(result_label.setText)
        combo.pathChanged.connect(print)

        lay = QtGui.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.addRow("Select: ", combo)
        lay.addRow("Result: ", result_label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**PyQt5:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

data =[{
        "Courses": ["Math", "Science", "English"]
    },
    {
        "Cars": ["Ford", "BMW", "Mercedes"]
    }
]

class ComboBoxExpandable(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    currentTextChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    pathChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def setData(self, value):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.setMenu(menu)
        self.append_element(value, menu)
        menu.triggered.connect(self.on_triggered)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAction)
    def on_triggered(self, action):
        self.setText(action.text())
        path = [action.text()] 
        w = action.parentWidget()
        while w.parentWidget() and isinstance(w.parentWidget(), QtWidgets.QMenu):
            path.insert(0, w.title())
            w = w.parentWidget()
        self.pathChanged.emit(path)
        self.currentTextChanged.emit(self.text())

    @staticmethod
    def append_element(value, menu):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for e in value:
                ComboBoxExpandable.append_element(e, menu)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            for k, v in value.items():
                ComboBoxExpandable.append_element(v, menu.addMenu(k))
        else:
            menu.addAction(value)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        combo = ComboBoxExpandable()
        combo.setData(data)

        result_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        combo.currentTextChanged.connect(result_label.setText)
        combo.pathChanged.connect(print)

        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.addRow("Select: ", combo)
        lay.addRow("Result: ", result_label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.How can i make this works for PyQt4?

Comment: @MS. You have to indicate the version in your question with a label. Now update my answer, try now. If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Hello, how can I initialize a default value of ComboBoxExpandable without to click it?