# Assigning values of a signal to a variable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

I'm new to signal and slots in python and currently designing a GUI with Pyqt5. User requires to select from a mix of qcombobox where each element is a qmenu. I'm trying to store the selection of the path user is taking using signals.

Image of selection GUI

[image]

**Attempt:**

Using the pathChanged in a class as:

```
pathChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
```

and later in the **init** print the selected path with:

```
combo.pathChanged.connect(print)
```

But this would not save the value of my path to a variable but just showing it on the console. If I equate the above to a variable, then I just receive the memory location.

How can I store the selections in a list and the list gets appended after each user selection?

Trying to implement the idea from the original code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52723148/6942881

And my code is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


data = {'Concept': {
            "Aircraft":{
                    "Blended Wing":[],
                    "Lifting Body":["Flat Bottom","Round Bottom","Wing"],
                    "Wing Body":["Fixed","Rotary","Swept"]},
            "Launch Vehicle":{
                    "SSTO":["Expendable","Reusable","Partially Reusable"],
                    "TSTO":["Expendable","Reusable","Partially Reusable"],
                    "MSTO":["Expendable","Reusable","Partially Reusable"]}
                    }
        }


class ComboBoxExpandable(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    currentTextChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    pathChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def setData(self, value):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.setMenu(menu)
        self.append_element(value, menu)
        menu.triggered.connect(self.on_triggered)
    def printer(self,path):
        # print(path)
        return path

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAction)
    def on_triggered(self, action):
        self.setText(action.text())
        path = [action.text()] 
        w = action.parentWidget()
        while w.parentWidget() and isinstance(w.parentWidget(), QtWidgets.QMenu):
            path.insert(0, w.title())
            w = w.parentWidget()

        self.pathChanged.emit(path)
        self.currentTextChanged.emit(self.text())
        self.printer(path)


    @staticmethod
    def append_element(value, menu):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for e in value:
                ComboBoxExpandable.append_element(e, menu)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            for k, v in value.items():
                if v==[]:
                    menu.addAction(k)
                else:
                    ComboBoxExpandable.append_element(v, menu.addMenu(k))
        else:
            menu.addAction(value)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        combo = ComboBoxExpandable()
        combo.setData(data)
        result_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        combo.currentTextChanged.connect(result_label.setText)
        combo.pathChanged.connect(print)
        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.addRow("Select Concept: ", combo)
        lay.addRow("Concept Selected: ", result_label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a slot connected to that signal where the list that is transported through the signal is added to a member of the class:

```py
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self._paths = [] # <---container
        combo = ComboBoxExpandable()
        combo.setData(data)
        result_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        combo.currentTextChanged.connect(result_label.setText)
        combo.pathChanged.connect(self.on_pathChanged)
        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.addRow("Select Concept: ", combo)
        lay.addRow("Concept Selected: ", result_label)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def on_pathChanged(self, path):
        self._paths.append(path) # append path
        print(self._paths)
```